# catkin_make can't find #include files

Tags: ros, catkin-make, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/jackson/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jackson/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/jackson/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target polygon_plugins
[ 50%] Building CXX object pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_loader.dir/src/polygon_loader.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_plugins.dir/src/polygon_plugins.cpp.o
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_plugins.cpp:2:47: fatal error: pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h>
                                               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_plugins.dir/src/polygon_plugins.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_plugins.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/src/polygon_loader.cpp:2:47: fatal error: pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h>
                                               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_loader.dir/src/polygon_loader.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pluginlib_tutorials_/CMakeFiles/polygon_loader.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

Here is the file tree:

```
pluginlib_tutorial_
- CMakeLists.txt
- package.xml
- polygon_plugins.xml
+ src
 - polygon_loader.cpp
 - polygon_plugins.cpp
+ include
 + polygon_tutorials_
  - polygon_base.h
  - polygon_plugins.h
```

I'm lost as to why `polygon_base.h` is not being found.

```
~/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials$ find . -name polygon_base.h
.include/pluginlib_tutorials_/polygon_base.h
```

I was concerned that maybe the include path was not looking in the "include" folder so I tried the absolute path as well

```
/home/users/jackson/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib_tutorials_/include/pluginlib_tutorials/polygon_base.h
```

Which still did not work. What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246872/catkin_make-can%27t-find-#include-files/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your CMakeLists.txt, you need to tell the compiler to look for include files in your `include` directory.

You can do this by adding the following line to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(include)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3